How to shorten generating a graph when trying to use breadth first search?
Im not sure how to explain this. Basically I am trying to do Leetcode problem "752. open the lock"
My solution was to use breadth first search algorithm. Basically:

Generate the 10,000 possible combination graph like so

graph{
0000:{0001,0010,0100,...9000},
.
.
.
9999:{9990,9909...0999}
}


use breadth first search to print out every single possible paths from start to end, save those paths into a 2d array.
as per the target and deadlocks start filtering every path


take out all those paths with deadlocks
take out all those paths where target is not the final value


get the length of the shortest path, minus 1 and then return it

When manually testing the testcases, it seems like my program works. But generating the 10,000 possible combinations took so long that when I submit, Leetcode gives time limit exceed error.
When using BFS, shouldn't there be an existing graph? But when generating the graph it takes too long to compute. So how do I go about generating a graph during the BFS dynamically, which could shorten the time to compute
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def generate_lock_graph():
        # Initialize the lock graph
        lock_graph = {}
        
        # Generate all possible combinations of lock digits
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                for k in range(10):
                    for l in range(10):
                        node = f"{i}{j}{k}{l}"  # Create a lock combination node
                        neighbors = []  # Initialize the list of neighboring nodes
                        
                        # Generate all possible moves for the current lock combination
                        for digit in range(4):
                            # Generate a new lock combination by incrementing the digit
                            new_combination = list(node)
                            new_combination[digit] = str((int(new_combination[digit]) + 1) % 10)
                            neighbors.append("".join(new_combination))
                            
                            # Generate a new lock combination by decrementing the digit
                            new_combination = list(node)
                            new_combination[digit] = str((int(new_combination[digit]) - 1) % 10)
                            neighbors.append("".join(new_combination))
                        
                        lock_graph[node] = neighbors
        
        return lock_graph

    @staticmethod
    def bfs(graph, start):
        global explored
        global queue
        global possiblePaths

        explored = []
        queue = [[start]]
        possiblePaths = [[start]]

        while queue:  # Creating loop to visit each node
            # Get current node
            path = queue.pop(0)
            node = path[-1]

            if node not in explored:
                neighbours = graph[node]
                for neighbour in neighbours:
                    new_path = list(path)
                    new_path.append(neighbour)

                    possiblePaths.append(new_path)
                    queue.append(new_path)
                explored.append(node)
        # print(possiblePaths)
        return possiblePaths

    def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
        graph = self.generate_lock_graph() #generate the graph
        allpaths = self.bfs(graph,"0000") #start bfs, give all possible path from start to finish
        allpaths = [path for path in allpaths if not any(deadend in path for deadend in deadends)] # remove all paths with deadends
        # allpaths = [path for path in allpaths if target in path] # remove all paths without the target
        allpaths = [path for path in allpaths if path[-1] == target] # remove all paths where target is not the final value
        # print(allpaths)
        if len(allpaths) == 0: # return -1 if no possible paths
            return -1
        else:
            return len(allpaths[allpaths.index(min(allpaths,key=len))]) - 1 # minus one to remove the first node, get the shortest list (shortest path)
solution = Solution()
# solution.bfs(graph,'0000')
deadends = ["0201","0101","0102","1212","2002"]
target = "0202"
print(solution.openLock(deadends,target))



Do not use a list as a queue; removing from the front takes linear, not constant time. Prefer collections.deque instead.
There is no need to generate an actual graph in memory. You can search for all the next combinations while running the BFS, making the code a lot simpler.
Use a set to store visited states instead of a list.

class Solution:
    def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
        dist = {}
        deadends_set = {(*map(int, s),) for s in deadends}
        src = (0,) * 4
        if src in deadends_set:
            return -1
        dist[src] = 0
        q = deque([src])
        dest = *map(int, target),
        while q and dest not in dist:
            curr = q.popleft()
            for i, d in enumerate(curr):
                for m in -1, 1:
                    nxt = curr[:i] + ((d + m) % 10,) + curr[i+1:]
                    if nxt not in dist and nxt not in deadends_set:
                        dist[nxt] = dist[curr] + 1
                        q.append(nxt)
        return dist.get(dest, -1)


"Do not use a list as a queue" - Hey hey, I do that all the time, more convenient and maybe also a little faster to simply do q = [src] for curr in q: ... q.append(...) ...

@nocomment That's true; I should qualify that statement with "if you're removing from the front".

Another answer already explains that no graph building is needed.
I would suggest working with integers instead of strings, and use two lists: one containing the nodes of the frontier of the BFS search, and another for collecting the new nodes that are reachable from that frontier. Then make that the frontier. That way you can easily count the depth of the BFS tree:
class Solution:
    def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
        if "0000" in deadends:
            return -1
        # BFS
        frontier = [int(target)]
        explored = set(map(int, deadends + [target]))
        distance = 0

        while frontier:
            if 0 in explored:
                return distance
            nextfrontier = []
            for state in frontier:
                for unit in 1, 10, 100, 1000:
                    for add in 9, 1:
                        digit = (state // unit) % 10
                        nextdigit = (digit + add) % 10
                        nextstate = state + (nextdigit - digit) * unit
                        if nextstate not in explored:
                            explored.add(nextstate)
                            nextfrontier.append(nextstate)
            frontier = nextfrontier
            distance += 1
        return -1

